# Id is added but not removed

Tags: jquery

When I click on the code button `<>` a second id is correctly added, but when I click on the code button again `<>` the new added id is not removed, so how can I remove the added id, since I have tried some alternatives and They don't work for me.

What I try to do is delete the following `id` `newID`

```
if (codeMode) {
    var formattedHtml = formatHtmlCode(htmlDiv.html());
    htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal"); //pre
    htmlDiv.text(formattedHtml);
    var editor = $("#editor");
    editor.addClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
    editor.attr('id', 'editor newID');
} else {
    htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal");
    htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
    var editor = $("#editor");
    editor.removeClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
    //editor.attr('id', 'editor');
    //$('div#newID').removeAttr('id');
    //editor.removeAttr( "newID" )
}
```

Snippet:

```js
 $(function() {
  function formatHtmlCode(str) {
   var div = document.createElement('div');
   div.innerHTML = str.trim();
   return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
  }
  function format(node, level) {
   var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
   indentAfter = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
   textNode;
   for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
    textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
    node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);
    format(node.children[i], level);
    if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
     textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
     node.appendChild(textNode);
    }
   }
   return node;
  }
  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
   switch ($(this).data('role')) {
    case 'p':
     document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
     break;
    case 'code':
     codeMode = !codeMode;
     if (codeMode) {
      var formattedHtml = formatHtmlCode(htmlDiv.html());
      htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal"); //pre
      htmlDiv.text(formattedHtml);
      var editor = $("#editor");
      editor.addClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
      editor.attr('id', 'editor newID');
     } else {
      htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal");
      htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
      var editor = $("#editor");
      editor.removeClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
      //editor.attr('id', 'editor');
            //$('div#newID').removeAttr('id');
            //editor.removeAttr( "newID" )
     }
     break;
    default:
     document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
     break;
   }
  });

  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
  htmlDiv.on('keyup', function(e) {
   if (!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
   } else if (e.shiftKey) {
    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
   }
  });

  htmlDiv.on("paste", function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
   document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
   document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  });

  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
   $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
   $(".editor-preview").keyup();
  });
  
  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function() {
   var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
   if (!codeMode) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
   } else {
    $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
   }
  });

 });
```

```css
#editControls {
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 1px solid transparent;
    border-left: 1px solid transparent;
    border-right: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: silver;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%; /*90*/
}
#editor {
    resize: vertical;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;/*90*/
}
#editor:focus { 
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}
.codeMode {
    font-family:Courier New,Source Code Pro Light,Medium,Source Code Pro ExtraLight,Menlo,Consola,Monaco Linux,Consola Regular,Fira Code Regular,DejaVu Sans Mono;
    /*font-family: inherit;*/
    /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
    border: 0px;
    font-style: inherit;
    font-variant: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    font-stretch: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    box-sizing: inherit;
    color: #fff;
}
.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
.btn-group {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.btn-group+.btn-group {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.btn-group a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn-editor {
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.42857143;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
    touch-action: manipulation;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background-image: none;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
    margin-left: -1px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}
.btn-not-space{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    border-radius: inherit;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
    background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}
#preview {
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 97%;
    border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
    clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-wrapper">
 <div id="editControls">
  <div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
   <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
   <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
   <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
   <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
  </div>
 </div>
  <div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
  <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
  <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
</div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n4ctd795/

Comment: what you want to achieve   ,  is it the black background    not  removing after toggling the edit mode?

Comment: The `content editable` div already has an `id` which is `editor`. On click of the `<>`, you change that for `editor newID`... **WRONG**. First, unlike classes, you cannot have more than one word for an ID. 2) If an element already has an ID and is looked up by the script using it, Don't change it! --- Unsure what you are trying to do here... But in any way, use an additional class. Don't mess up the `id`.

Comment: @Fernando   if you want to fix the problem of black background see my answer ,  if  there's is other thing  needs to be added tell me

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette I want to enable the ace.js script only when I go to the black mode, that is to say the code mode, I tried to do it that simple way, since ace.js does not function with a .class but with a #id yes.

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan I want to enable the `ace.js` script only when I go to the black mode, that is to say the code mode, I tried to do it that simple way, since `ace.js` does not function with a `. -> class` but with a `#id` yes.

Comment: where that ace.js file   , does it run on load ,

Comment: is this the full code or what

Comment: @Rkv88-Kanyan that is enabled only using a specific id, but this action I only want to enable when in code view mode, so I tried to use another id https://jsfiddle.net/kdr31qh9/2/

Comment: hi ,  why  you don't  use the Acejs  API  to manipulate the content & replacing text  ,  in the background  then when clicking codemode view editor & hide the other element  so  make them seperate

Comment: Hi @Rkv88-Kanyan I don't understand how it would be, could you help me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

by adding & removing classes you can toggle the code mode

don't need to alter id in any situation

https://jsfiddle.net/rkv88/61xbkfto/

```
if (codeMode) {
    var formattedHtml = formatHtmlCode(htmlDiv.html());
    htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal"); //pre
    htmlDiv.text(formattedHtml);
    var editor = $("#editor");
    editor.addClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
} else {
    htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal");
    htmlDiv.html(htmlDiv.text().replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, ""));
    var editor = $("#editor");
    editor.removeClass("black-bg-colr codeMode");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I now understand what you attempt to do. When hitting `<>`, you want to edit the text in a "code view"...

So here is how I changed your project (without the ace.js instance, which is about color coding the code):

1. I use a "sub div" to show the code (with the black background style), declared as the `codeDiv` variable.
2. I squarely replace the `#editor` (main editor) content with the `formatHtmlCode` result, wrapped by the `codeDiv`.
3. When going out of the "code edition mode", I get the `codeDiv` content to turn it back into HTML and put it back in the main editor. Then I remove the `codeDiv`.

Now this does not use `ace.js`...
I will edit this solution when I'll find how to use it this way. It is an interesting question ;)

```js
$(function() {

  let codeMode = false;
  let htmlDiv = $("#editor");
  htmlDiv.css("white-space", "normal"); // This could be set via CSS rule

  // Use a "sub div" to show the code
  let codeDiv = $("<div id='codeDiv' class='black-bg-colr codeMode'>")

  function formatHtmlCode(str) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = str.trim();
    return format(div, 0).innerHTML;
  }

  function format(node, level) {
    var indentBefore = new Array(level++ + 1).join('  '),
      indentAfter = new Array(level - 1).join('  '),
      textNode;
    for (var i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
      textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentBefore);
      node.insertBefore(textNode, node.children[i]);
      format(node.children[i], level);
      if (node.lastElementChild == node.children[i]) {
        textNode = document.createTextNode('\n' + indentAfter);
        node.appendChild(textNode);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }

  // HTML editor's buttons
  $('#editControls a').click(function(e) {
    switch ($(this).data('role')) {

      case 'p':
        document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, $(this).data('role'));
        break;

        // The <> code button
      case 'code':
        codeMode = !codeMode;
        if (codeMode) {

          // Format the text with the HTML tags in a "code sub div"
          var formattedHtml = formatHtmlCode(htmlDiv.html());
          codeDiv.text(formattedHtml);
          htmlDiv.html(codeDiv);
        } else {

          // Retrieve the modified HTML from the "code sub div" and overwrite the content... So the "codeDiv" is removed de facto. Simple!
          htmlDiv.html($("#codeDiv").text())
        }
        break;

      default:
        document.execCommand($(this).data('role'), false, null);
        break;
    }
  });


  htmlDiv.on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (!e.shiftKey && e.keyCode === 13) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'p');
    } else if (e.shiftKey) {
      document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    }
  });

  htmlDiv.on("paste", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = (e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
    document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, 'div');
    document.execCommand('insertText', false, text);
  });

  htmlDiv.on("input", function(e) {
    $(".editor-preview").val(htmlDiv.html());
  });

  $('.editor-preview').keyup(function() {
    var contentAttr = $(this).attr('class');
    if (!codeMode) {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(value);
    } else {
      $('.' + contentAttr).html(htmlDiv.text());
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#editControls {
  overflow: auto;
  border-top: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid transparent;
  border-right: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: silver;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: .5em 1em .5em 1em;
  background-color: #fbfbfb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor {
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 1em;
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  /*90*/
}

#editor:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 2px silver;
}

.codeMode {
  font-family: Courier New, Source Code Pro Light, Medium, Source Code Pro ExtraLight, Menlo, Consola, Monaco Linux, Consola Regular, Fira Code Regular, DejaVu Sans Mono;
  /*font-family: inherit;*/
  /*font-family: 'Courier New';*/
  border: 0px;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-variant: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-stretch: inherit;
  line-height: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  box-sizing: inherit;
  color: #fff;
}

.black-bg-colr {
  background-color: #000 !important;
}

.btn-group {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group+.btn-group {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.btn-group a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn-editor {
  height: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -ms-touch-action: manipulation;
  touch-action: manipulation;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-group>.btn-editor+.btn-editor {
  margin-left: -1px !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-not-space {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-editor.btn-not-space:hover {
  background-color: rgba(230, 230, 230, 0.32);
}

#preview {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 97%;
  border-top: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #c8ccd0;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="editor-wrapper">
  <div id="editControls">
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="bold" data-ref="#"><b>Bold</b></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="italic" data-ref="#"><em>Italic</em></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="underline" data-ref="#"><u><b>U</b></u></a>
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="strikeThrough" data-ref="#"><strike>abc</strike></a>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group">
      <a class="btn-editor btn-not-space" data-role="code" data-ref="#"><code>&lt;/&gt;</code></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="editor" contenteditable>
    <b>Hello! Use the &lt;/&gt; button to modify me.</b>
  </div>
  <textarea id="textarea" name="detail" class="editor-preview" style="display: none;"></textarea>
  <div id="preview" class="editor-preview"></div>
</div>
```